# Creating button in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

This is my button in activity_main.xml

```
    <Button
        android:text="@string/fs"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" 
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.451"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.069" android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button" 
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:onClick="flowerpage"/>
```

This is the button being created I believe in the Mainactivity.kt

```
fun flowerpage(view: activity2) {
}
```

I am new to Kotlin, however, I used to HTML where you could connect two web pages together via HTML link, however, this doesn't seem to be as simple.

```
    button2.setOnClickListener {flower_button()}
```

this shows compiler error. am I missing an import..??

Comment: That function is not creating the `Button`. That's just the target function for your `onClick` attribute, though it currently has the wrong parameter type, and will crash if you try to use it. An `Activity`'s `View`s are created from its layout in the `setContentView()` call. It's not really clear what your actual question is, however.

Comment: I understand that the command I am creating in mainactivity.kt is not the actual visual button, thanks tho..

Comment: What is the actual problem, then?

Comment: So at this point in time I am taking the other answers advice and trying to create an onclicklistener
    button2.setOnClickListener {flowerpage()}  
however this causes a compiler error,

Comment: which is followed by
    private fun flowerpage(){
        val intent = intent(this, activity_activity2.class)
                startactivity intent
    }
which I would hope cause button2 to issue the function flowerpage which starts intent which is activity_activity2.class

Comment: Please be specific about the errors and Exceptions you get. Anyway, if you're just trying to start another `Activity`, all you had to do to the code originally posted was change the parameter type in `flowerpage()` from `activity2` to `View`, and then `startActivity(Intent(this, activity2::class.java))` inside that method, assuming the class name for that second `Activity` is `activity2`.

Comment: Awesome I was able to add all that without any red marks, it still says that flowerpage and view are in grey and are not called to.
   private fun flowerpage(view: View) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, Activity2::class.java))
    }
}

Comment: If you mean it's saying that they aren't used anywhere, then, yeah, that's to be expected. You don't need the `View` parameter at all, because you're currently not interested in which `View` was clicked, and the `flowerpage()` method isn't called anywhere in your code, so it just doesn't think it's being used. They're just warnings. You can ignore them, in this case.

Comment: Btw, don't forget to add an `<activity>` element in your manifest for `Activity2`, if there's not one there already, otherwise you'll get an `ActivityNotFoundException` when you try to start it.

Comment: Okay so at this point in time could I create a button2.setOnClickListener{flowerpage()}
to set a click listener on button2 to execute function flowerpage?

Comment: The `onClick` attribute you have in the layout XML will cause an `OnClickListener` that calls that `flowerpage()` function to be created and set automatically during the `setContentView()` call. You don't necessarily need to set up your own `OnClickListener` for this. I will mention, though, that the `onClick` attribute technique apparently causes trouble for some users in certain setups. With a basic learning project, though, you likely don't have anything that would cause an issue.

Comment: With the onClick attribute applied i still receive the app closing when I try to press the button. On the XML i get red underneath the "flowerpage" as it doesn't even recognize the fun flowerpage() in the .kt

Comment: That function must be directly in `MainActivity`, not inside anything else therein. I just did a quick test, and it took Android Studio a minute to realize that it's there, but it works as expected when run.

Comment: I am reopening my android studio to see if that helps, I was getting method has incorrect signature in my .xml on the "flowerpage" onclick button
after reopening I still get "Method 'flowerpage' in 'Mainactivity' has incorrect signature"

Comment: Did you remember to change it to `fun flowerpage(view: View)`, as I mentioned above?

Comment: yup yup,
    }
    private fun flowerpage(view: View) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, Activity2::class.java))
    }
}

Comment: It cannot be `private`. Remove that modifier.

Comment: Okay cool, it does a spellcheck which i'm assuming has nothing to do with code? and my fun flowerpage now turned yellow instead of grey... my (view: view) is grey tho

Comment: it worked thank you! I apologize for sounding so novice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With kotlin you just need to give your button an id in the XML, then you can do this:

```
btn_id_you_gave.setOnClickListener {doSomething()}

private fun doSomething() {...}
```

You don't need to do the OnClick thing in the XML you want to take max advantage of Kotlin.

Comment: So when I do that what would I put into {} to make the app go to activity2? So far I can see that I am issueing button2 (buttonid) to dosomething, which means the user will dosomething once the press the button, what's the syntax to move to activity2 once they issue the dosomething command.
setcontentview(activity2)?

Comment: i get compiler error

        button2.setOnClickListener {flower_button()}

    private fun flower_button(){
        val intent = activity_main(application, activity_activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

Comment: To go to another activity you can use something like this:

startActivity(Intent(this, Activity2::class.java))

The intent needs a context, so if you're doing the intent in one activity you can use "this", if it's in a fragment you have to use "getcontext".